# Setting two or more variables of a Java Object using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, executorservice

I have this object as follows:

```
@Builder
@Data
public class Person
   private String firstName;
   private int age;
```

What I am trying to do is get a `Person` object or a `Person.Builder` object in which it has set these two values (`firstName` and `age`) in two separate threads. The reason why is because I have to make network calls to get these two values and they are not dependent on each other.

Right now I can think of something like this:

```
Callable<String> nameCallable = () -> nameService.getName(personId));
Callable<Integer> ageCallable = () -> ageService.getAge(personId);

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
Future<String> nameFuture = executor.submit(nameCallable);
Future<Integer> ageFuture = executor.submit(ageCallable);

return Person.builder().name(nameFuture.get()).age(ageFuture.get()).id(personId).build();
```

I am trying to find a different solution because with this approach I do not know which thread finished first `ExecutorCompletionService` but I can't use that because my Futures have a specified return type (String and Name). Also, if I had all the callables having the same return type, I can define the callable as a `@Bean` and autowire all callables into a `List<Callable<T>>` and in my `executor` i can do `invokeAll`

If anyone has any ideas on how to accomplish what I'm doing and any tips or pointers, please let me know,

Thanks

Comment: why not make two `CompletableFuture`s, wait for both to happen and create a `Person` with the result you got from them?

Comment: @Eugene - can you share some source code for what you are suggesting? Plus what would be the advantages of doing that?

Comment: Why do you think it matters “which thread finished first”?